# Retrieving Dailymotion popular videos

Tags: dailymotion-api

I want to retrieve popular videos on Dailymotion without login. Youtube has an API for the same. Is there any API available to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "sort" parameter with rated, visited ...

Something like https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?sort=visited

See here for more [infos](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html).